# How to use multiple colors in a TextField in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
List<String> dataTypes = const <String>[
'int',
'double',
'num',
'Byte',
'bool',
'byte',
'short',
'int',
'long',
'float',
'double',
'boolean',
'char'
];
  
 List<String> keywords = const <String>[
'async',
'await',
'break',
'case',
'catch',
'class',
'const',
'continue',
'default',
'deferred',
'do',
'dynamic',
'else',
'enum',
'export',
'external',
  ];



 List program = [];

  Color syntaxColor(){
for(int i = 0; i<program.length; i++){
  for(int j = 0; i<dataTypes.length; j++){
    if(program[i] == dataTypes[j]){
      return Colors.orange;
    }
  }
}

for(int i = 0; i<program.length; i++){
  for(int j = 0; i<keywords.length; j++){
    if(program[i] == keywords[j]){
      return Colors.blue;
    }
  }
}
return Colors.black;

}



Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title:Text("Code Editor"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    child: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.99 ,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.blueGrey
          )
      ),
      child: TextField(
      maxLines: 36,
      onChanged: (value){
        setState(() {
          program.add(value);
        });
      },
      style: TextStyle(
        color: syntaxColor() 
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        )
      ),
      
    ),
    ),
  ),
);
 }
```

Here i have implemented to use the multiple colors for the different strings if any of the string matches the string datatypes list then it will display in the orange color and if any of the string matches the string keywords list then it will be displayed in the blue color and rest of the string who don't matches the any of the string in both of the lists then it will be displayed the black color.

I have implemented this code but its not working.

Comment: Please make your question much clearer to understand. From what I understood, you want to check if a text in a list is equal to another text in another list. For that, I would use list.where(). Take a look at: https://codeburst.io/top-10-array-utility-methods-you-should-know-dart-feb2648ee3a2 . There is no need to use two nested for loops. Your code is extremely inefficient. For understanding programming fundamentals, take a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlxmoA0rQ-LyHW9voBdNo4gEEIh0SjG-q

Answer (score 7):

How about you use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/rich_text_controller/example).
Here is example related to package.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rich_text_controller/rich_text_controller.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'RichText Controller Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: RichTextControllerDemo()),
    );
  }
}

class RichTextControllerDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RichTextControllerDemoState createState() => _RichTextControllerDemoState();
}

class _RichTextControllerDemoState extends State<RichTextControllerDemo> {
  RichTextController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = RichTextController(
      {
        RegExp(
          "num|Byte|bool|byte|short|int|long|float|double|boolean|char/g",
        ): TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        RegExp(
          "async|await|break|case|catch|class|const|continue|default|defferred|do|dynamic|else|enum|export|external/g",
        ): TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
      },
      onMatch: (List<String> matches) {},
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: TextField(
      controller: _controller,
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: TextFormField(
        controller: _controller,
      ),),
    );
  }

Comment: I have added that controller to an TextFormField but i am getting error

Comment: The method 'call' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: call()

Comment: I have also done the same but i am getting an error

Comment: NoSuchMethodError: The method call was called on null. Receiver null

Comment: Okay i have got it the problem is with the onMatch: method

Comment: but how to match those list items

Comment: Please check again. I checked that error and resolve that error. I double confirmed with this code whether it works well.

Comment: Yes i have done with that error but how to match those string who are in lists because there are two lists

Comment: How to match the list in that regex expression

Answer (score 3):

You can use [rich_text_controller](https://pub.dev/packages/rich_text_controller) package. There is an onMatch property in it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'rich_text_controller/rich_text_controller.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'RichText Controller Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: RichTextControllerDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class RichTextControllerDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RichTextControllerDemoState createState() => _RichTextControllerDemoState();
}

class _RichTextControllerDemoState extends State<RichTextControllerDemo> {

// Add a controller
RichTextController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
      // initialize with your custom regex patterns and styles
      _controller = RichTextController({
           //
          //* Returns every Hashtag with red color
          //
          RegExp(r"\B#[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b"):TextStyle(color:Colors.red),
         // add as many expressions as you need!

         //! starting v1.1.0
         // Now you have an onMatch callback that gives you access to a List<String>
         // which contains all matched strings
         onMatch: (List<String> matches){
           // Do something with matches.
           //! P.S
           // as long as you're typing, the controller will keep updating the list.
         }
         //!
      });
    super.initState();
  }
}
```